# Module installation in python returning "Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement" error?

Tags: python, pip, python-3.4, 32-bit

Unfortunately I cannot install any modules on `python 3.4 32 Bit` using the pip command due to the following error.

[image]

How do I get around the problem. I have removed all other installations of `python` and have installed the `32 Bit` version rather than the `64 Bit` one?

Thanks

**Edit 1:**

At the moment I can't even upgrade pip

[image]

**Edit 2**

Unfortunately it still returns an error.

[image]

Comment: This looks more like a network error to me, since it cannot even reach the index (that is working right now)

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading your pip with

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

If this fails too, it has to be a network problem. See if you're properly connected to internet.

Seems like you might be using an old version of PIP which is facing SSL certification issues and is hence unable to connect. You can do a manual reinstall of pip using these commands.:

```
python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools
```

Then, download this [script](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

Finally, run the script with:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Comment: I am afraid I can't attempt to upgrade since the same error is returned

Comment: I am connected. Speeds are looking normal and I can access https://pypi.python.org/simple/ using a browser just fine.

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'

Comment: It seems to return this error,Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:598) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip